# Limit Amount of Words In a Div

Tags: html, css, wordpress, content-management-system

[Here](http://accountabletest.com/) is where the  3 boxes are. All of them share the same amount of characters. Inside the boxes I need the text to be limited so that If the user insert more text, the last word is followed by ... preventing the content to override the box.

> I've already tried with text-overflow: ellipsis;

But I believe I'm using it wrong. As If I add more text to each box, the text overrides the box.

Answer (score 2):

`text-overflow: ellipsis` only works with the following combination: fixed width, overflow hidden and `white-space: nowrap;` the elipssis does **not work with mulitple lines**.

You should use something like this: http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/

**Single line example**: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hx7hA/)

```
.ellipsis {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Which browser support that?

Comment: @Niels, your code works fine horizontally, but I have a squared box. So I need to fix just a couple of lines inside...I've just tried adding height, but no luck..How could I fix it?

Comment: That's why I say the `text-overflow: ellipsis` does not work with multiple lines. You need an alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

`text-overflow` will only have an effect if the `white-space: nowrap` is set which means you cannot use it to truncate text which is more than one line.

This means you're stuck with truncating the text on the server or using javascript. There are a few good jQuery plugins out there for this, something like [dot dot dot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) should do the trick.

Comment: Exactly, The effect works just with one line. And you understand perfectly the issue Im facing. Still, The plugin you recommend me is not available for wordpress.. @Godwin

Comment: The jQuery plugins can be installed in Wordpress, they are just not WordPress plugins. They are also only really good if you have text that is being resized on the fly. Wordpress has a built in function to deal with this: the_excerpt (http://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt). You can customize using filters to return any length of text and add whatever you want for your ellipses ('...', 'read more', ...)